# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' and del from list error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, int

I'm trying to read in a text file and check if my scores is high enough to be saved, the lowest score is to be thrown out. Now I get an error when comparing two integers saying one is a string.

I'm running python under windows 10 and this code worked fine until I started it with "py datasave_test.py" in cmd. Now i always get this error.
the `del highscores[lowest_score]` part is also not working anymore.

```
player_score = 3000
with open('testscores.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        highscores = line.split(",")
    highscores.append(player_score)
    lowest_score = int(highscores[0])
    for i in range (1, len(highscores)):
        if int(highscores[i]) < int(lowest_score):
            lowest_score = highscores[i]
    lowest_score = int(lowest_score)
    del highscores[lowest_score]
    highhelper = ''
    for i in range (0, len(highscores)-1):
        highhelper += str(highscores[i])+","
    highhelper += str(highscores[len(highscores)-1])
    print(highhelper)
    with open('testscores.txt', 'w') as outF:
        outF.write(str(highhelper))
    print("kicking out score: "+str(lowest_score))
```

Comment: Show the traceback

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dusti\Google Drive\UNI\BS_RN\Übung\Projekt\datasave_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    del highscores[lowest_score]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: So a completely different error?

Comment: Kinda, I'm getting this and the first error randomly without changing anything. I'm setting up an ubuntu virtual machine right now to see if these errors also happen there.

Comment: Your `highscores` is a weird list of strings (from `.split()`) and a number 3000. You should not convert `lowest_score` to an integer to remove it. Note that only the last line of the file is included, all others are discarded. There are many other issues with your code.

Comment: Sorry I'm entirely new to python. The number 3000 is the new score that is supposed to be added and lowest score is my starting point from where i compare it to every score in my list to finally kick the lowest one out.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the file? I created ```testscores.txt``` and added the following to it ```200,400,500``` and it worked. Check if you have a trailing comma at the end and remove it

Comment: `testscore.txt` looks like that: `200,1200,50,50,50,50,50,3009,3000,3000`